# Error using amazon EC2(ubuntu)

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2

I just started using amazon EC2 and I use it via cygwin on windows to run ubuntu. I recently tried logging in to my EC2 instance by ssh and I got this error message

```
@    WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!     @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
IT IS POSSIBLE THAT SOMEONE IS DOING SOMETHING NASTY!
Someone could be eavesdropping on you right now (man-in-the-middle attack)!
It is also possible that a host key has just been changed.
The fingerprint for the ECDSA key sent by the remote host is...
 Host key verification failed.
```

What is this, and how I do I get around this?

Answer (score 4):

This means the SSH server is presenting a different RSA key than when you first connected to the server on this IP address. If you changed the instance running on this IP address/hostname, this should be expected.

If this is a completely unexpected error message, this is for your own protection. There's a chance someone could be doing something malicious and monitoring the connection.

If you want to override it, go to `C:\Users\[your username]\.ssh\known_hosts` and remove the offending line that starts with the hostname and/or IP address of the SSH server. Then reconnect to the server.

Comment: Thanks I tried this but it gives me a message that no such file or directory

Comment: Try looking for `%USERPROFILE%\.ssh\known_hosts` (`known_hosts` is a file) in Windows Explorer, unless you have done something non-standard to your home directory in cygwin.

Answer (score 3):

just use

`ssh-keygen -R hostname`

example ssh-keygen -R 168.9.9.2

This will update the offending of your host from the known_hosts

Answer (score 0):

When you connect to an ssh server your ssh client keeps a list of trusted hosts as key-value pairs of IP and ssh server fingerprint. With ec2 you often reuse the same IP with several server instances which causes conflict.

If you have connected to an earlier ec2 instance with this IP, and now connect to a new instance with the same IP your computer will complain of "Host verification failed" as its previously stored pair no longer matches the new pair.

The error message tells you how to fix it:

eg:
Offending RSA key in /home/ubuntu/.ssh/known_hosts:1
remove with: ssh-keygen -f "/home/ubuntu/.ssh/known_hosts" -R

simply open /home/ubuntu/.ssh/known_hosts and delete line 1 (as indicated by the ":1").

You can now connect and receive a new host verification